# Using array length when using $slice

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to get the length of array `posts` and use that in the `$slice` operation?

```
  Feed.find(
                { owner: { $in: joinedFeeds } },
                { posts: { $slice: [<length>, fetcher] } }
              )
```

My goal is to fetch a certain amount of posts each time I call a route. So, i'd like to take the last slice of the array

Comment: Do you want to use size of array in place of <length>, then I would guess what you get is empty array !! How does your posts look like and can you provide desired o/p..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the data of my collection:

```
db.test.insert([
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "description" : "product 1", colors: [ "blue", "black", "red" ] ,'fav':["1","2"]},
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "description" : "product 2", colors: [ "purple" ],'fav':[] }
])
```

Please check below query that will fetch the elements from 'colors' array based on the length of 'fav' array for that record.

```
db.test.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         finalTotal: {
            $let: {
               vars: {
                  numberOfColors: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$fav" }, then: { $size: "$fav" }, else: "NA"} }
               },
               in: { $slice: [ "$colors", "$$numberOfColors" ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }

] )
```

Please let me know if this is helpful and also in case you face any issue with implementation of same.